# PHP and SQL login form using sessions

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

I am trying to create a simple login form for my website. I have a very basic HTML form that points to a php file. I do not need security or any of that stuff.. I am looking for something very basic. I'm really not sure where I am going wrong here. When I try and sign in using information already in mysql it still brings me back to the login page instead of bringing me to my account page.

HTML

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="well well-sm">
              <form class="form-horizontal" action="actLogin.php" method="post">
              <fieldset>
                <legend class="text-center">Sign In</legend>


                <!-- Message body -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Username">Username</label>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Your email" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="text" placeholder="Your email" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Form actions -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                    <button onClick="return validateForm()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                 ` </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

PHP

```
session_start();

//Get username and password from the form.
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"username");
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"password");

//Call the database and check to make sure the password matches
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","MIS42520!$") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("cookie",$conn);

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$sql = "select id, username, password from universal where username = '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    header('Location: login.php');

}

$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

if ($password != $userData['password']) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
else {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['id']=$userData['id'];
    $_SESSION['username']=$userData['username'];
    $_SESSION['password']=$userData['password'];
    session_write_close();
    header('Location: account.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: and what is your question?!

Comment: Please tell us what's the problem with your code. What do you expect? And what do you actually get?

Comment: I just want it to work and its currently not working.. it keeps bringing me back to the login page even when I sign in with the correct info

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sql = "select id, username, password from universal where username = '".$username."'";
```

Add a variable in the redirection to know where the system is redirecting to the login page, something like:

```
header('Location: login.php?var=1');
```

And

```
header('Location: login.php?var=2');
```

In the second one.